# Flutter: how to create custom shader

Tags: flutter, shader

I want to create custom camera preview pixelate filter:
[Example Pixelate IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrbHY.png)

Code to add gradient filter:

```
home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
      ),
      body: ShaderMask(
        shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
          return LinearGradient(
            colors: <Color>[Colors.green, Colors.deepOrange, Colors.blue],
            tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
          ).createShader(bounds);
        },
        child: AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio:
            controller.value.aspectRatio,
            child: CameraPreview(controller)
        ),
      )
  )
```

[Example Gradient IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0M7ii.png)

There is no shader in flutter for this and I didn't find how to create custom shader.

Comment: Have you tried using `PlatformView` ?

Comment: Check out BoxShadow

Comment: @yosh did you mean create own plugin and implement this on each ios and android?

Comment: No, but you can do that. I saw someone talking about using PlatformView

Comment: @Maadhav Sharma I don't understand how it would be help.

Comment: @yosh I hope that it can be easy )) But I will check.

Comment: Let me know if it works and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @user8994242 You wanted add shadow to a image right?

Comment: @Maadhav Sharma No I want to create custom camera preview pixelate filter

Comment: [youssef ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11252816) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69501823) saying "Custom shaders are on the way currently check this [https://github.com/flutter/flutter/projects/207#card-63772055](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/projects/207#card-63772055)"

Comment: I achieved the pixel effect by enlarging the picture and then reducing it